# Transform linkedhashmap into org.w3c.dom.Element

Tags: java, xml, dom, linkedhashmap

I need to create a method that given any LinkedHashMap , this method have to transform it into XML/Dom elements of a Document like :

```
@Override
    public Element marshal(Object linkedHashMap) {

       Document doc = DocumentBuilderFactory.newInstance().newDocumentBuilder().newDocument();
       final Element element = doc.createElement("root");

       //For each attribute and object of the linked hashmap
       // I must iterate recursively in order to get all the objects and atributes of the LinkedHashMap and append them to the root node element:

       //element.appendChild(...));

      return element; // here the element must be already populated with all the attributes of the linked hashmap and its values.
    }
```

I have no idea about how can I achieve this , how can I loop through the attributes of a LinkedHashMap in order to map them to Element ?

I need something like this , but it must iterate over all the levels and sublevels (nested linkedhashmap objects) of the linkedhashmap:

```
 private void marshalMapElements(ArrayList<LinkedHashMap> linkedHashMaps) {
        Document doc = getDocument();
        Element root = doc.createElement("root");
        for (Map<String, Object> element : linkedHashMaps) {
                Element e = doc.createElement(element.getKey());
                e.setTextContent(element.getValue());
                root.appendChild(e);
            }
        }
    }
```

Comment: Are you sure you want to do that yourself? Mapping objects to XML has been done zillions of times before, so why not just get a library and save time?

Comment: Because I cannot find any library that mapps/marshal an Object to a org.w3c.dom.Element object

Comment: Are you mapping to XML or to `org.w3c.dom.Element` objects? Because they're 2 distinct things.

Comment: I'm mapping  to org.w3c.dom.Element . I've changed the title :)

Comment: did you ever resolve this question? i'm stuck in a similar position...

Comment: No, I didn't find any answer